# phonegap barcode scanner is not working first time in android

Tags: cordova

I am new for Phonegap, in my app I have to scan barcode,so i have used the following .js file for scanning.this js file is called from HTML page. in iOS it is working fine,but in android it scans only even time, odd time it is not scanning the barcode. could any one fix this Issue?

```
var app = {
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
        document.getElementById('scan').addEventListener('click', this.scan, false);
    },
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');
        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');
    },
    scan: function() {
        var scanner = cordova.require("cordova/plugin/BarcodeScanner");
        scanner.scan(function(result) {
            window.location.href = "scan?id=" + result.text;
        }, function(error) {
            alert("scan function error");
            console.log("Scanning failed: ", error);
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. I've just added next line to config.xml and it started to work ok.

```
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.3.0" />
```